# how to search a string with space in django search method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

when I search the **first_name** and **last_name** field together it won't display the result

eg: serch_text = "harry potter "
it does not include the space?

views.py

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
        search_text = request.GET.get('search')
        if search_text is not None and search_text != u"":
            search_text = request.GET.get('search')
            print(search_text)
            wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(Q(user__customer__first_name__icontains=search_text) |
                                            Q(user__customer__last_name__icontains=search_text) |
                                            Q(user__customer__email__icontains=search_text) |
                                            Q(user__customer__phone__icontains=search_text))
        else:
            wallets = Wallet.objects.all()
        html = render_to_string('customer/wallet-filter.html', {'wallets': wallets},
                                request)
        return JsonResponse({'html': html})

    wallets = Wallet.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    

    return render(request, 'customer/wallets.html', {'wallets': wallets})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **annotate method**

```
wallets = Wallet.objects.annotate(
                fullname=Concat('user__customer__first_name', Value(' '), 'user__customer__last_name')).filter(
                Q(user__customer__first_name__icontains=search_text) |
                Q(user__customer__last_name__icontains=search_text) |
                Q(user__customer__email__icontains=search_text) |
                Q(user__customer__phone__icontains=search_text) | Q(fullname__icontains=search_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `icontains`, the filter will check if any of of your model fields does fully include the string 'harry potter'.

If `search_text` can contain multiple strings seperated by whitespace, you could split these names into a list. Then your filters could check, if your model fields match one of these search strings.

```
search_text  = search_text.split(' ')  # Split search_text into list of multiple strings

wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(
    Q(user__customer__first_name__in=search_text) |  
    Q(user__customer__last_name__in=search_text) | 
    Q(user__customer__email__in=search_text) |        
    Q(user__customer__phone__in=search_text)
)
```

**EDIT**
If first and last name should both match the search text you have to use two filter statements as described in here:

```
wallets = Wallet.objects.filter(
    Q(user__customer__first_name__in=search_text)
).filter(    
    Q(user__customer__last_name__in=search_text) | 
)
```

Comment: it didn't work @15353043

Comment: What didn't work? Which traceback did you receive?

Comment: first_name and last_name is two fields in database so when i searched harry potter it also shows harry with other names some like harry peter also show

Comment: Then you are using the wrong query. Currently you are checking if the first name is included OR the last name is included. I updated the query.